# C++ program for Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am tryint to make a program on Binary Tree.There is problem in `deleteValue()`. If I do not call `deleteValue()` the program runs perfectly.But if I call `deleteValue()` it shows binaryTree.exe has stopped working.

deleteValue() Function

```
void deleteValue(T val)
    {
       // Node* temp =root;
        Node* node = search(root,val);
        Node* parent;
        Node* child;

        //leaf node
        if(node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr)
        {
          if(parent->left == node) parent->left == nullptr;
          else if(parent->right == node) parent->right == nullptr;

          delete node;
          return;
         }

        //node having only one child
        //replace it with its child and delete
        if((node->left == nullptr && node->right != nullptr)|| (node->left != nullptr && node->right == nullptr))
        {
          if(node->left == nullptr && node->right != nullptr)  //right child present
            {
            if(parent->left == node) //line 198
            {
                parent->left = node->right;
                delete node;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = node->right;
                delete node;
                return;
            }
        }
        else //left child present
        {
            if(parent->left == node)
            {
                parent->left = node->left;
                delete node;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = node->left;
                delete node;
                return;
            }
        }
   }

    //Node with 2 children
    // replace node with smallest value in right subtree
    if (node->left != nullptr && node->right != nullptr)
    {
        Node* chkr;
        chkr = node->right;
        if((chkr->left == nullptr) && (chkr->right == nullptr))
        {
            node = chkr;
            delete chkr;
            node->right = nullptr;
            return;
        }

        else // right child has children
        {
            //if the node's right child has a left child
            // Move all the way down left to locate smallest element

            if((node->right)->left != nullptr)
            {
                Node* lcurrp = node->right;
                Node* lcurr = minimum(lcurrp);

        node->data = lcurr->data;

                lcurrp->left = nullptr;
                 delete lcurr;
                 return;
           }
           else
           {
               Node* tmp;
               tmp = node->right;
               node->data = tmp->data;
           node->right = tmp->right;
               delete tmp;
               return;
           }

        }
         return;
    }
    }
```

binaryTree.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class BinaryTree
{
  struct Node
    {
        Node* parent;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        T data;
        Node(T const& val):parent(nullptr),left(nullptr),right(nullptr),data(val) {}

         // This is the move constructor
        // It moves the content of `val` into the node. For
        // types like vectors this is much more efficient as it
        // simply means copying three (or so) pointers and thus
        // transferring the internal containers without the cost
        // of copying all the elements in the vector.
        Node(T&& val):parent(nullptr),left(nullptr),right(nullptr),data(std::move(val)) {}

         //to enter any number and type of arguments
        template<typename... Args>
        Node(Args&&... args):parent(nullptr),left(nullptr),right(nullptr),data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

        ~Node()
        {
            delete left;
            delete right;
        }
    };
struct Node* root;

public:
    BinaryTree():root(nullptr) {}
    BinaryTree(BinaryTree const&)            = delete;
    BinaryTree& operator=(BinaryTree const&) = delete;
    ~BinaryTree()
    {
        delete root;
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return root == nullptr;
    }

     //returns node of the element
    Node* search(Node* root, T val) const
    {
        if(root == nullptr||val == root->data) return root;

        if(val < root->data) return search(root->left,val);

        else return search(root->right,val);
    }

    Node* minimum(Node* root)
    {
        while(root->left != nullptr)
            root = root->left;
        return root;
    }

    Node* maximum(Node* root)
    {
        while(root->right != nullptr)
            root = root->right;
        return root;
    }

    //Successor - a node which has the next higher key
    Node* successor(Node* node)
    {
        if(node->right!=nullptr) return minimum(node->right);

        Node* temp = node->parent;

        while(temp != nullptr && node == temp->right)
        {
            node = temp;
            temp = temp->parent;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //Predecessor - a node which has the next lower key
    Node* predecessor(Node* node)
    {
        if(node->left != nullptr) return maximum(node->left);

        Node* temp = node->parent;

        while(temp != nullptr && node == temp->left)
        {
            node = temp;
            temp = temp->parent;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    void insertValue(T const& val)
    {
        Node* node = new Node(val);
        Node* parent;
        node->left = nullptr;
        node->right = nullptr;
        parent = nullptr;

        if(isEmpty()) root = node;
        else
        {
            Node* curr = root;
            while(curr)
            {
                parent = curr;
                if(node->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
                else curr = curr->left;
            }

            if(node->data < parent->data) parent->left = node;
            else parent->right = node;
        }
    }

     void insertValue(T&& val)
    {
        Node* node = new Node(std::move(val));
        Node* parent;
        node->left = nullptr;
        node->right = nullptr;
        parent = nullptr;

        if(isEmpty()) root = node;
        else
        {
            Node* curr = root;
            while(curr)
            {
                parent = curr;
                if(node->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
                else curr = curr->left;
            }

            if(node->data < parent->data) parent->left = node;
            else parent->right = node;
        }
    }

    template<typename... Args>
   void insertValue(Args&&... args)
   {
        Node* node = new Node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        Node* parent;
        node->left = nullptr;
        node->right = nullptr;
        parent = nullptr;

        if(isEmpty()) root = node;
        else
        {
            Node* curr = root;
            while(curr)
            {
                parent = curr;
                if(node->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
                else curr = curr->left;
            }

            if(node->data < parent->data) parent->left = node;
            else parent->right = node;
        }
    }

 void deleteValue(T val)
    {
       // Node* temp =root;
        Node* node = search(root,val);
        Node* parent;
        Node* child;

        //leaf node
        if(node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr)
        {
          if(parent->left == node) parent->left == nullptr;
          else if(parent->right == node) parent->right == nullptr;

          delete node;
          return;
         }

        //node having only one child
        //replace it with its child and delete
        if((node->left == nullptr && node->right != nullptr)|| (node->left != nullptr && node->right == nullptr))
        {
          if(node->left == nullptr && node->right != nullptr)  //right child present
            {
            if(parent->left == node) //line 198
            {
                parent->left = node->right;
                delete node;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = node->right;
                delete node;
                return;
            }
        }
        else //left child present
        {
            if(parent->left == node)
            {
                parent->left = node->left;
                delete node;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->right = node->left;
                delete node;
                return;
            }
        }
   }

    //Node with 2 children
    // replace node with smallest value in right subtree
    if (node->left != nullptr && node->right != nullptr)
    {
        Node* chkr;
        chkr = node->right;
        if((chkr->left == nullptr) && (chkr->right == nullptr))
        {
            node = chkr;
            delete chkr;
            node->right = nullptr;
            return;
        }

        else // right child has children
        {
            //if the node's right child has a left child
            // Move all the way down left to locate smallest element

            if((node->right)->left != nullptr)
            {
                Node* lcurrp = node->right;
                Node* lcurr = minimum(lcurrp);

        node->data = lcurr->data;

                lcurrp->left = nullptr;
                 delete lcurr;
                 return;
           }
           else
           {
               Node* tmp;
               tmp = node->right;
               node->data = tmp->data;
           node->right = tmp->right;
               delete tmp;
               return;
           }

        }
         return;
    }
    }

  void inOrder(Node* node)
  {
      if(node != nullptr)
      {
          if(node->left) inOrder(node->left);
          std::cout<<" "<<node->data;
          if(node->right) inOrder(node->right);
      }
      else return;
  }

  void print_inOrder()
  {
      inOrder(root);
  }

  void preOrder(Node* node)
  {
      if(node != NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<" "<<node->data;
        if(node->left) preOrder(node->left);
        if(node->right) preOrder(node->right);
    }
    else return;
  }

  void print_preOrder()
  {
      preOrder(root);
  }

  void postOrder(Node* node)
  {
      if(node != NULL)
    {
        if(node->left) postOrder(node->left);
        if(node->right) postOrder(node->right);
        std::cout<<" "<<node->data;
    }
    else return;
  }

  void print_postOrder()
  {
      postOrder(root);
  }
};

int main()
{
   BinaryTree<int> bt1;
   bt1.insertValue(100);
   bt1.insertValue(20);
   bt1.insertValue(30);
   bt1.insertValue(400);
   bt1.insertValue(50);
   bt1.print_inOrder();
   std::cout<<"\n";
   bt1.print_preOrder();
   std::cout<<"\n";
   bt1.print_postOrder();
   bt1.deleteValue(20);
   std::cout<<"\n";
   bt1.print_inOrder();
   std::cout<<"\n";
   bt1.print_preOrder();
   std::cout<<"\n";
   bt1.print_postOrder();


    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting

```
 20 30 50 100 400
 100 20 30 50 400
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After debugging I am getting error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048c4e in BinaryTree<int>::deleteValue (this=0xbfffed04, val=20) at bt1.cpp:206
206                     parent->right = node->right;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a `Node`, it deletes both child nodes as well (`left` and `right`).  Within `deleteValue`, you copy the left (or right) node to the parent then delete node.  This will delete that left (or right) node, and the parent will have a dangling pointer to it.

One way to fix this it to null out both left and right pointers within `Node` before deleting it (when removing that node).